# How to configure a ThreadPool for parallel webservice requests?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, web-services, parallel-processing

I want to send webservice calls to a webservice in parallel. There should be a maximum of 20 parallel requests waiting for a webservice response. Any other requests should wait for them to finish.

If a single user sends a request to me, this usually leads to sending 5 parallel requests to the target server.
So I could serve a maximum of 20/5 = 4 users at a time instantly. Others would have to wait, which is fine. Or being rejected on really high load.

Question: which thread pool should I use for this, and how should I configure it?

```
private ExecutorService asyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
    executor.initialize();

    //return executor.getThreadPoolExecutor(); //I could as well use this. Which is better??
    return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20, executor);
}
```

I read the above as follows: the main pool can send 20 parallel requests to the webserver (thereby serve 4 users instantly in parralel). If all 20 threads are busy and a 5th user comes in, the requests are queued.

Question:

- It the configuration correct?
- Why do I have to set the `nthreads=20` in `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()` additionally? What is the difference in setting the `poolSize`?
- Is there a performance overhead of setting the `corePoolSize=20`? I mean, then the pool will never thrink. But I could probably not set it lower (eg to 5), because new threads are only created if the queue is exhausted. Right?

Comment: If you look more closely at `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`, you will find it to be a `ThreadFactory` and a wrapper over `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor` class. Call to `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` accepts an instance of `ThreadFactory`, and creates another `ThreadPoolExecutor` that wraps given thread factory. You don't need to tell your config data two times if you just use one or the other and not wrap it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that

```
executor.setMaxPoolSize(20)
```

can be used to override initially set # of threads via constructor, it seems redundant in this case. Same applies to `setCorePoolSize`. It's just for dynamic control.
As per size of the pool, in general you may consider [Little's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law)

Comment: So should I 1) remove the `Executors.newFixed...()` statement and use `executor.getThreadPoolExecutor()` to construct the `ExecutorService`? Or should I remove the pool configurations and rely on `Executors.newFixed...()`?

Comment: @membersound, you definitely don't need both. Which one you should choose depends on whether you want to submit using Spring's API or use JDK API.

Comment: @membersound Choose either one of them, I see no difference. In general I would suggest to use `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` for such a relatively small task.

Comment: But how can I limit the `queueSize` if using `Executors.` interface?

Comment: If you want to gain more dynamic control you would launch via 
ExecutorService, otherwise via Executors.

Comment: @membersound, you don't need to use `Executors` class, just instantiate `ThreadPoolExecutor` directly. Its constructor will give you exactly what you want: it allows you to specify `core` and `max` pool sizes (1 and 20 in your case), as well as "keep-alive" and choose queue implementation. For most of these I would recommend using same values as `Executors` class does.

Comment: OK so I'll drop `Executors` interface here. But I assume I have to set the `corePoolSize=maxPoolSize`, because otherwise the core pool would only be increased if the *queue* is full (and thus I would not have parallelized requests for single user requests)?

Comment: @membersound, yes, that's correct. I might've forgotten that you wanted to start off with having 20 active threads at all times. But in this case you can just use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20)`.

Comment: I could probably, but I want to limit also the queue capacity (so on highload some user requests are just rejected due to queue rejection policy). So I probably just have to stick to `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` bean.

Comment: @membersound, or you give `ThreadPoolExecutor` a bounded queue, such as `LinkedBlockingQueue` with appropriate capacity.

Comment: Ok, using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity()` triggers the creation of the executor with  `LinkedBockingQueue`. So this is probably the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20, executor);` you are passing previously set up executor as a **ThreadFactory**, because ThreadPoolTaskExecutor implements ThreadFactory interface.

The result is an ExecutorService that starts with 20 threads ready, maximum number of threads 20 and an unbounded LinkedBlockingQueue for tasks waiting to be processed (you can see it here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int,%20java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory)).

So as to your first and second question- you can omit Executors.newFixedThreadPool() call and just return ThreadPoolTaskExecutor or call getThreadPoolExecutor() on it if you want to work with jdk class ThreadPoolExecutor.

As to your thrid question- there will be a penalty at a startup because jvm will have to create and run 20 threads but I guess thats negligible. One thing that will give you setting corePoolSize to something lower than maximumPoolSize is that unsed threads will be killed by jvm which can reduce the memory footprint of your application.

As to when new threads are created in ExecutorService- threads in ExecutorService are created when there are tasks in the queue and maximumPoolSize is not reached. If maximumPoolSize in executor is reached and queue is full- executor will throw RejectedExecutionException for every new task submitted to it, untill there is room again for a new ones. You can change this behaviour by implementing your own RejectedExecutionHandler.